# Show Attached Image to Post on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, attachment

How i can show attached images of my posts on Wordpress?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this in your single.php template:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => 'image',
'post_parent' => $post->ID
);
$images = get_posts( $args );
foreach($images as $image):
echo wp_get_attachment_image($image->ID, 'medium');
endforeach;
```

Comment: I'm starting to realize that there is no beautiful solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_get_attachment_image`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)