# How to display the images attached to a post inside the admin?

Tags: wordpress

Hello stackoverflow friends!

Hopefully somebody here can help me with this! I've looked all over the internet with no luck :(

What I want to do is somehow show the images attached to a post inside the WP admin. For example, the same way the post Featured Image shows. The only thing I found was how to display the number of attachments of a post in the admin columns but what I would like to see is thumbnails of all attached images inside each post in the post admin page. I think this will be very helpful since right now I cannot even tell which post has attachements.

I will like to accomplish this without using a plugin.

I have looked for days online with no luck. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

```
   /* === Add Thumbnails to Posts/Pages List === */
if ( !function_exists('o99_add_thumbs_column_2_list') && function_exists('add_theme_support') ) {

    //  // set your post types , here it is post and page...
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array( 'post', 'page' ) );

    function o99_add_thumbs_column_2_list($cols) {

        $cols['thumbnail'] = __('Thumbnail');

        return $cols;
    }

    function o99_add_thumbs_2_column($column_name, $post_id) {

            $w = (int) 60;
            $h = (int) 60;

            if ( 'thumbnail' == $column_name ) {
                // back comp x WP 2.9
                $thumbnail_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', true );
                // from gal
                $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image') );
                if ($thumbnail_id)
                    $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id, array($w, $h), true );
                elseif ($attachments) {
                    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
                        $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, array($w, $h), true );
                    }
                }
                    if ( isset($thumb) && $thumb ) {
                        echo $thumb;
                    } else {
                        echo __('None');
                    }
            }
    }

    // for posts
    add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'o99_add_thumbs_column_2_list' );
    add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'o99_add_thumbs_2_column', 10, 2 );

    // for pages
    add_filter( 'manage_pages_columns', 'o99_add_thumbs_column_2_list' );
    add_action( 'manage_pages_custom_column', 'o99_add_thumbs_2_column', 10, 2 );
}
```

it will show you the featured image as preview in the manage post /page list , 
If you want to show it inside the post itself - use @Calle suggestion:
(modified here to work)

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'o99_add_attach_thumbs_meta_b' );

function o99_add_attach_thumbs_meta_b (){

add_meta_box ('att_thumb_display', 'Attached images','o99_render_attach_meta_b','post');

}

function o99_render_attach_meta_b( $post ) {
$output = '';
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );
    //
    // uncomment if you want ordered list
    //
    // $output .= '<ul>';
     $images = get_posts( $args );
    foreach(  $images as $image) {
    //$output .= '<li>';
        $output .= '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $image->ID ) . '" />';
        //$output .= '</li>';
    }
   // $output .= '</ul>';
  echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Hi Obmerk Kronen, I really appreciate your help. I tried your solution and this only shows the first attachment in the admin columns. I will like to see the thumbnails from all attachments inside the Post View admin section if is possible to do. Thank you so much!

Comment: then like i said - use @calle solution

Comment: You are my hero!!! this is exactly what I was looking for! it worked to perfection!!! Thank you sooo much Obmerk Kronen and @calle for being so helpful!

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to create a meta box and then put the thumbnails in there. This requires the [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function and [wp_get_thumb_attachment_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_thumb_url). We also need to find all attached images of a certain post, which we'll do using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815158/show-attached-image-to-post-on-wordpress).

Putting all this together, and assuming PHP version >= 5.3 so that we can use anonymous functions, it will look like this:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', function() {
add_meta_box( 'att_thumb_display', 'Attachmed images', function( $post ) {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID
    );

    echo '<ul>';
    foreach( get_posts( $args ) as $image) {
        echo '<li><img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $image->ID ) . '" /></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}, 'post' );
});
```

The argument of `add_meta_box` that I've set to "post" indicates on which post type this meta box will be available. If you want it available on pages, you have to set it to pages. Or if you want it to be available on a custom post type, you will also have to modify it accordingly.

I hope this works. I haven't tried it.

Comment: Hi Calle, first of all, thank you so much for your comment. I tried the code above but nothing happens. I don't see any changes inside my admin panel. I am not too good in PHP but looking at the code I believe this is too display the images in the page code to be seen by your visitors (in the front end). I will like to see the thumbnails in the post admin panel. Thank you!

Comment: I am kink of a newbie at this so could be that I might be missing something. I added your code inside the functions.php Thank you!

Comment: Hi Calle, I found this which is very close to your solution: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16386/creating-a-metabox-to-upload-multiple-images-ignoring-the-featured-image)  This actually displays the attachements!! but is on top of the page. I believe is just missing the part in which to wrap it around a meta box. How could I accomplish that? Thank you! Adding: @Obmerk Kronen

Comment: While reviewing the code I noticed that I'd missed a semicolon. I'm surprised you didn't an error message. But yes, you put this code in functions.php (copy it over again since I added that semicolon). It will create a box underneath the text editor in the back end panel, for blog posts only.

Comment: Hi Calle, yes, I did get an error when I entered the first time and noticed the missing semicolon, I had added it and still didn't see it coming up.

Comment: Well, try now again because I changed the context parameter of add_meta_box as well.

Comment: Hi Calle, THANK YOU sooo much for your help!!! @Obmerk Kronen put together a combination using your code that worked beautifully! Thank you guys so much you are the best!

Comment: OK, glad it worked for you. I don't see any modifications except forgoing the use of anonymous functions. So if that was all that was required you probably don't have PHP >= 5.3. That was probably what was at fault.

Comment: @ calle, I believe `wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $image->ID )` . but anyhow, I Still think op should have acceped your answer . +1 from me anyhow ..

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't see that typo. I updated it now if someone stumbles on this in the future, thx :)

Comment: If my custom post type is campaign,  how do I modify this?  "if you want it to be available on a custom post type, you will also have to modify it accordingly." ? I have tried multiple ways of doing it and nothing seems to work correctly.

Comment: @user1488639 It was many years ago now that I wrote this, all I can tell you is that it has to do with the last argument `'post'` in the `add_meta_box` function. Look that up in the documentation. Probably, you can replace it with `my_custom_post_type`.